# Retrieve cookies from browser in stand alone app

Tags: java, cookies

I want to access the cookies from my browser (for example firefox) IN my java stand alone app. Can I access the cookie database or is that generally a bad approach? Is there an API that might help be solving this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookies are stored by the browser in it's own, proprietary form, i.e. each browser can store it in a different way. The format could even change between releases of the same browser. There are no public APIs available to ask a browser for it's cookie-db. Therefore it doesn't make sense to try to build a generic solution which tries to access a browser's cookie db.

If you want to create an application just for yourself and want to use the firefox cookies db, then this is not a problem and should work. Firefox is open source and you can see how it stores it's cookies in a its db. The more recent versions use a sqlite db, and the file is stored here https://superuser.com/questions/387372/where-does-firefox-keep-cookies

Answer (score 0):

The usual way how these kind of apps are implemented is by sending user to the 'connecting page' which then with javascript calls your own apps URI, such as myapp://auth?auth_code=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX_XXXXXXXXXXXXXX_XXXXXXXXXXX

This requires you to make your Java application handle URIs and implement the cookie passing via URI on the page you're using, here's information how to [perform this in Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx), I am not sure which platforms you're targeting, but I am sure there's also a general fit library that handles all the cases.

I didn't find any general resources targeting Java, but this is a much solved problem and there's various implementations.